# C# public members visibility of a class with no namespace

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, dependencies, visibility

I have a project that I publish as **MyNuget** package in a local feed. The project references a **ThirdPartyNuget** that has `ThirdPartyExtensions` public static class with public extension methods over `IQueryable`.

Now, in my main solution I reference **MyNuget** and DO NOT reference **ThirdPartyNuget**. Still, Visual Studio 2022 shows the extensions methods from `ThirdPartyExtensions`. Why?

I do not expect this as I consider **ThirdPartyNuget** the implementation detail of **MyNuget**.

The assemblies in **ThirdPartyNuget** are obfuscated and `ThirdPartyExtensions` class looks weird as it has no namespace. Here is what I see in the debugger:

```
typeof(ThirdPartyExtensions).Name == typeof(ThirdPartyExtensions).FullName == "ThirdPartyExtensions"
typeof(ThirdPartyExtensions).Namespace == null
typeof(ThirdPartyExtensions).GUID == {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
```

What's the mechanics of this behavior?

How do I hide the visibility of `ThirdPartyExtensions`  in my main solution?

Comment: I think this should be blamed to the third party package, who defined the class in no namespace. And you can't fix it.

Answer (score 7):

If you use `PackageReference` format for your package dependencies,
`PrivateAsset` tag in your `MyNuget` `.csproj` may do the trick.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets

> You might be using a dependency purely as a development harness and might not want to expose that to projects that will consume your package. In this scenario, you can use the PrivateAssets metadata to control this behavior.

```
<PackageReference Include="ThirdPartyNuget" Version="1.0.0">
    <PrivateAssets>compile</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

Or you can use `developmentDependency` in `packages.config` as described in this question:
[Don't include dependencies from packages.config file when creating NuGet package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15012963/3872935)

---

In terms of question: "why public dependencies is the default way?", I would say: It makes life easier.

It's easier to consume packages with public dependencies. And it's easier to make them public if it's default behavior.
For example, many packages for web development depended on `Newtonsoft.json`. And to configure serialization, it was needed to expose it. [Another opinion about that.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58117840/3872935)
Probably guys from MS have some statistics about it. But I didn't see any articles about that. They only [recommend it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference) as the default way.

---

In terms of your case, I'am not sure that I correctly reproduced it.

In my test I've created three projects:
One subPackage with empty default namespace.
[image]
One package with reference to SubPackage with PrivateAssets attribute.
[image]
[image]
And project, which references Package, but not references SubPackage.
[image]
It doesn't compile if I try to use extensions.
But prints '2' in runtime, if I use `GetNumber` method.

And if I've understood question correctly it's the desired result.
But I'm not sure, will it work for your patched `ThirdPartyNuget` package or not.

Comment: Thank you, Kote! Setting `PrivateAssets` flag removes `NugetSubPack.dll` from the bin output folder of the main package. So I can compile it but cannot use it, getting "System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly" at run time.

Comment: @UserControl, thank you. Yes, the previous example was wrong, it didn't copied `NugetSubPack.dll`. The correct way is marking only `compile` assets as private.  `<PrivateAssets>compile</PrivateAssets>`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't declare a namespace for your class, then the default global namespace is used.The global namespace is the namespace that contains namespaces and types that are not declared inside a named namespace. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/namespace-alias-qualifier).

You can see classes which are not have namespace using `global` keyword. The `global` keyword is the global namespace alias only when it's the left-hand identifier of the `::` qualifier.For more information read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/namespaces#138-qualified-alias-member)

`In my main solution I reference MyNuget and DO NOT reference ThirdPartyNuget`. BUT your `MyNuget` referenced to `ThirdPartyNuget`. It means, your project will be referenced to `ThirdPartyNuget` as well.

It is not possible to hide the visibility of extensions, BUT...

Your expectation and goal is looks strange. Hovewer, you can do something like this:

If your goal is: do not allowing to use that extensions method in your projects that uses `MyNuget` you can create the same extensions classes with empty namespace. For example, `ThirdPartyNuget` project has this extension (without namespace):

```
public static class ThirdPartyExtensions
{
    public static void DoSome(this string value)
    {
        //Do some
    }
}
```

Just create the same class in `MyNuget` and try to use this in your project. You will get ambiguous error from compiler :).

So, it will not hide it, but it will not allow to use this extension

Comment: Hmm, interesting. But if a developer fixes the namespace conflict by introducing an alias he will still be able to call functions from `ThirdPartyNuget`, won't he?

Comment: @UserControl He cannot. Both of them are under the global namespace.